# Run javascript if AJAX responce is a certain length of characters

Tags: javascript, ajax

How would you run a segment of javascript if the AJAX response was a certain amount of characters?

What I have so far is:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: action,
data: form_data,
success: function(response)
{
if(length == 7)
//success
else
//unsuccessful
```

Although the response that the script is getting is 7 characters long, the else script still seams to run. What would the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: action,
  data: form_data,
  success: function(response)
  {
    if(response.length == 7)
    //success
    else
    //unsuccessful
  }
});
```